# MYSQL BLOB vs TEXT Field with search query

Tags: mysql, database, search, mariadb, blob

I am designing a mysql database and I need your help, please.
I have a table with large texts (from internet, word, emails...) and I will do search in these texts. For example, I need to know all the texts that contains the world 'Fox'. Most of the access of the table will be for reading, but sometimes I will need updates.
And because of these I have 2 questions:

1) Which one is better for this situation : BLOB or TEXT?
2) Is it better to build 2 separate tables with one containing the texts that will never be updated (those from internet, for example) and the other with the texts that the user will update? And if the answer to this question is YES, which one i shall use in each table?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for `BLOB` vs `TEXT`, it depends on the contents you expect.  I would think `TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` would be appropriate for today.

As for the other questions; it sounds like "premature optimization".  Do whatever is simpler for now.  But plan to revisit performance and other issues after you have enough data to test with.